# Elucidate the differences: Sequential vs Concurrency vs Parallel vs Distributed vs Synchronous vs Asynchronous vs Client-Server vs OSI Model?

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, distributed, synchronous, sequential

Sequential vs Concurrency vs Parallel vs Distributed vs Synchronous vs Asynchronous vs Client-Server vs OSI Model

I understand that...

- sequential, concurrent, parallel, and distributed seem to be in the same class
- synchronous and asynchronous are in the same class (different types of input/output)
- client-server is a distributed model for the internet, but I don't know if all client-servers are distributed (for instance, what is an x-server?)
- I think the OSI model is the stack of protocols for the client-server model in distributed computing, but I am not positive.
- all sequential is asynchronous?
- all distributed/concurrent/parallel is synchronous?

Can somebody make a Venn diagram or at least describe in terms of sets how they intersect with each other? I would also appreciate any more depth that somebody is willing to provide in an explanation.

edit: We could add multithreading and multiprocessing too

Comment: I am unsure as to what is being asserted / asked.

Comment: Could you compare and contrast these terms? Show the relations?

Comment: No, not really: why? Because many run orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

- Asynchronous execution is non-blocking, it is executed without waiting it to complete, you can carry on with other things. Starting thread, pushing object to queue which is monitored by threads, web service which returns tracking id to come and check for the status later etc.
- Parallelism is running multiple things at the same time. In Java, the fork/join provides support for parallel programming by splitting up a task into smaller tasks to process them using the available CPU cores. Java 8's parallel streams and the method Arrays#parallelSort use under the fork/join framework to execute parallel tasks.